# Are salutations, sign-offs and other politese appropriate?

Tags: discussion, editing

Recently physics.SE has seen more users regularly including salutations and sign-off in their posts. That [behavior has been strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021) for a very long time, and I would prefer the same here. But I'm not ready to start a major editing campaign without polling the locals.

See also:

- [Editing for Brevity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37439/2509) (Closed as a duplicate of the above, but much more recent and containing some additional discussion.)

Thought?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

see https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures

> #### Can I use a signature or tagline?
>
> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

It is forbidden by the faq, and continuing to do it when politely being asked to refrain is grounds for timed suspension.

Answer (score 3):

I am very old and very old-school.
I like these pleasantries and think they help avoid flame wars.
I violated this rule on my first few posts out of ignorance.
But now I am trying to comply.
(I find this is a fairly complex and more than slightly intimidating site for a newbie, but maybe that's just me.)
Now I am strongly tempted to end with a complimentary close, and a signature,  but I won't.

Comment: I use them pretty obsessively in other contexts, too, but to me they seem *visually* redundant and annoying the way things are laid out around here. On top of which those we have a asker and answerer relationship these are not one-to-one communications: they go to many recipients.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been particular about it so far, but if there are not vehement objections from the community, I would be fine going along with a plan to edit them out. We can then make this an `[faq]` question to refer people to in the future when they wonder why the greetings etc. have been stripped out of their posts.

Answer (score 2):

In the originial [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021) [dmckee](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/520/dmckee) is mentioning the argumentation is all about **effectiveness** and getting the content of something straight.

I agree that it is important to come to a point fast.
But: This is a question of which **culture** one wants to have in such a community. The *extraneous clutter* mentioned by [TheTXI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22164/thetxi) might indeed be something meaningful in **human communication**.

So I strongly plead to leave the **freedom** to the members of our community in which way to personalize questions and answers - I think I am not just a machine creating content for some website...

Comment: Agree with @robert filter. But I am a visitor here and I don't make the rules here. however much I might personally prefer a welcoming culture, I'll obey those rules.