# Why might providing contact information be considered spam?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, policy, moderation

My [(now changed) answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/341300/1) to the question,"Why is $PV^γ$
constant in an adiabatic process?" received the following comment:

> 1. You do not need to "archive" the question in your answer, that's what the revision history is for. 2. Suggesting people contact you at your website in an answer is inappropriate, and your repeated pattern of doing so borders on spam. Please stop doing this. 3. Information like pointing OP formatting help should be done in comments not answers - answers should contain solely information pertaining to the actual question posed. – ACuriousMind♦ 18 mins ago

1. What is he trying to say?
2. What site policies is he referring to?

I am no longer able to update my answer there (currently locked out), getting the following message from his actions:

[image]

Is this answer really spam-like; if so, why; if not, what can be done to allow me to once more edit the question?

## Post-Script:

I found the following [HTML formatting link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed) to be very useful for general formatting.  And this [equation formatting link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9906/how-can-i-type-the-isomorphic-not-equal-and-the-set-of-integers-rationals) was also very helpful. Thank you Physics Stack Exchange!

Comment: Your copy of the answer here has an added paragraph on "Sterling Engines" [sic] that wasn't in the answer you wrote originally. Is this added paragraph intentional? The way the question is written makes it seem as if you're saying this paragraph was in the original answer.

Comment: The site maintains a full revision history of all questions and answers, so there is no need to "archive" the original post here. Accordingly, I've edited it out.

Comment: You can see what this revision history looks like by clicking the "edited X time ago" link to the left of the post author card.  That edit history link shows the identity of the most recent reviser, if the reviser is a different user than the post's original author.

Answer (score 7):

1. I am trying to say precisely what I wrote there.
2. I am referring, among others, to [this policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/360/50583) about salutations, taglines and links to your own stuff not directly related to the question, which you have been informed about before in [this earlier comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340131/where-does-all-the-mass-created-from-energy-go/340157#comment762344_340157).

Continually calling upon people to contact you and leaving your own website's address in everything you post is considered spam because **that's what it is** - you are using physics.SE posts to promote your website when it has no relevance to the topic at hand.

To be able to edit your post, you should just reload that page - the message you are getting is the standard message for the case where another user has edited a post you are in the process of editing, and has nothing to do with you being "locked out".

Comment: This is a good place to emphasize that spam-like advertising (including undisclosed authorship of the blog post referenced, and the misleading indication of said blog post as a paper) is the reason that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338017), which OP continuously references, should not be undeleted in its current form.